# What is the function of this code?

Tags: c++

Can someone please explain to me how this piece of code works? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
int a[3] = { 9, 3, 4 };

for (int i = 2; i > 0; i--) {
    a[0] -= a[i];
}

cout << a[0];
```

Comment: Is this really C?

Comment: Step through it. What happens to the array `a`?

Comment: Whatever it does, it is not C, but C++

Comment: For a much more useful result, the array should read `int a[3] = { 49, 3, 4 };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be answered by doing a bit of research on google, as it is a very simple program. However, here is a quick explaination:

```
int a[3] = { 9, 3, 4 };
```

This line creates an array that can hold 3 integer values. The values assigned are:

- a[0] = 9
- a[1] = 3
- a[2] = 4

Then in the for-loop condition:

```
for (int i = 2; i > 0; i--) {
```

A counter int is declared and set to 2. The for loop runs while the counter is greater than 0. After every run, the counter is decremented by 1. If you notice, it runs for `i` equal to 2 and 1, which covers a[2] and a[1], but NOT a[0]

For every run, the first element of array `a` is decremented by the value at `a[i]`

In the end, the first element is printed out. Here, `9 - 3 - 4 = 0`

Comment: "it runs for i equal to 2, 1, **but not** 0."

Comment: My bad, @Potatoswatter, fixed that. Thanks for pointing that out!